# how can i change this code to make mouse over tabs?

Tags: jquery, wordpress, tabs

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    var panelContainer = jQuery('div#panels');
    jQuery('<div id="tabs"></div>').insertBefore(panelContainer);   
    panelContainer.find('div.panel').each(function(n){
        jQuery('div#tabs').append('<a class="tab" href="#' + (n+1) + '">' + jQuery(this).attr('title') + '</a>');
    });

    var panelLocation = location.hash.slice(1);
    if(panelLocation){
        var panelNum = panelLocation;
    }else{
        var panelNum = '1';
    }
    panelContainer.find('div.panel').hide();
    panelContainer.find('div.panel:nth-child(' + panelNum + ')').fadeIn('slow');
    jQuery('div#tabs').find('a.tab:nth-child(' + panelNum + ')').removeClass().addClass('tab-active');
    jQuery('div#tabs').find('a').each(function(n){
        jQuery(this).click(function(){
            panelContainer.find('div.panel').hide();
            panelContainer.find('div.panel:nth-child(' + (n+1) + ')').fadeIn('slow');
            jQuery(this).parent().find('a').removeClass().addClass('tab');
            jQuery(this).removeClass().addClass('tab-active');
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

inside `jQuery('div#tabs').find('a').each(function(n){` and after (or before) click handling

add this code:

```
jQuery(this).mouseover(function(){/* stuff */})
```

Comment: Thanks the code now is: panelContainer.find('div.panel').hide();
 panelContainer.find('div.panel:nth-child(' + panelNum + ')').fadeIn('slow');
 jQuery('div#tabs').find('a.tab:nth-child(' + panelNum + ')').removeClass().addClass('tab-active');
 jQuery('div#tabs').find('a').each(function(n){
  jQuery(this). mouseover(function(){
   panelContainer.find('div.panel').hide();
   panelContainer.find('div.panel:nth-child(' + (n+1) + ')').fadeIn('slow');
   jQuery(this).parent().find('a').removeClass().addClass('tab');
   jQuery(this).removeClass().addClass('tab-active');
  });
 });
});

Comment: Thanks stecb, and by the way can I make it auto rotate and stop on mouse over??